# Big confusion in surface tension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, capillary-action

I am a high school student and I am very confused in the concept of surface tension and capillary rise phenomenon, my school level textbooks is very ambiguous about it they first tell you that the weird shape of meniscus is due to the fact that liquids in equilibrium cannot sustain tangential stress so it will become perpendicular to the resultant force due to cohesion and adhesion

On the other hand when they explain capillary rise , they will consider the surface tension force due to solid interface on liquid, I wonder why we are considering surface tension now, if we had already considered cohesive and adhesive force to explain the shape of meniscus , as surface tension also arise due to cohesion, isn't it? and first they are telling that liquid cannot sustain tangential stress and now they are considering surface tension force tangential to the liquid surface why? Aren't both of these statements very contradictory? please explain it only in brief taking care of my knowledge to grasp the answer, I look up to several questions which are similar but the explanation given to them is either very complicated or not very clear.

Comment: A liquid in equilibrium can’t sustain a *net* tangential force, but it can definitely sustain a state in which a tangential force balances with other forces; indeed, a tangential force is necessary in these cases for equilibrium to apply.

Comment: can u please give some more details on what u are saying, it would be very helpful